# Why in result of the implicit conversion we get the -128?

Tags: c++, char, int, implicit-conversion

We have the following C++ code

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int  A = 128;
    char B = A;
    A = B;
    std::cout << "B:= " << B << std::endl; 
    std::cout << "A:= " << A << std::endl; 
    return 0;
}
```

Can anybody explain me, why in result we get the -128 ?

Comment: coz char overflow see [ref](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types) a signed char may have limits of -128 to 127

Comment: What happens with `unsigned char`?

Comment: `char` is evidently signed in your case (it is not necessarily so) - hence 128 -> 0x80 -> -128.

Comment: @PaulR +1 for showing the conversion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because on your system a `char` type has a range of `-128` to `127`.

`128` won't fit into a `char` on that system so it gets converted (in an implementation-defined way) to the value `-128`.

When you assign it back to the `int` variable, there's no problem with it holding the value `-128`, so that's what it gets.

As a note: int this case the implementation converts the value `128` `(char) -128` because `128` is represented in binary as `10000000`, which happens to be a signed 8-bit representation for `-128`. This will hold true for a large number of implementations.